# Source code management

Tags: version-control, repository

we are team of 4 at present. We all are working on the same project. Every morning we have to spend at least 30 minutes integrating our projects for all the changes we made previous day. 
Which tool can we use for this ?

Comment: This *must* have been asked before, and with a much better problem description at that.

Comment: This is too subjective to have a single answer unless you provide more specifics on your workflow, platform, processes and requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is a distributed source control system. You can put a repository on a shared network drive or use a commercial service such as github.

http://github.com

Answer (score 1):

The most popular ones at the time of writing seem to be subversion, git, and mercurial.

Subversion is a central-server SCM, trying to be similar to CVS, its now obsolete predecessor.

Git and mercurial are distributed SCMs, which has a number of advantages over central-server solutions, too many to elaborate. They also perform much better than subversion in terms of execution speed, data security, ease of use, and merge conflict resolving, so I suggest you go with one of these.

Comment: Thanks I have a better picture now

Answer (score 1):

An very easy way to create and manage source code repositories is the SCM-Manager. It is a open source tool that you can get for free at http://www.scm-manager.org. It is bundled with all the stuff you need to setup git, mercurial or subversion (or mixed) repositories and manage user and access rights.

Answer (score 1):

You should start using a version control system and a CI tool in order to know if your builds are fine every time that you push your code to your Git repository. For the version control system, I recommend you to use [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and as a CI tool, [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). You can also use both tools with a provider which permits you to have a Git repository as a Service and a Jenkins instance as a Service. In this way, you will have everything on the cloud and you will not need to install anything on your end.